# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\sqrt{\pi}$ solution doubts

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\sqrt{\pi}$

I tried to solve the problem by checking if the function series was convergent and then pass the limit under the integral but I was not able to solve the integral so I turned to the book solution, which looked complex.

**Solution**:

> We divide $(-\infty,\infty)$ into three parts as:
> $(-\infty,-n^{-\frac{1}{3}})\cup [-n^{-\frac{1}{3}},n^{-\frac{1}{3}}]\cup[-n^{\frac{1}{3}},\infty]$
> which we denote by $A_1,A_2,A_3$ respectively. For $1\leqslant k\leqslant 3$ >we put $I_k=\sqrt{n}\int_{A_k}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$
>
> Substituting $t=\sqrt{n}x$ we have
> $I_2=\sqrt{n}\int_{A_2}\exp(-n\log(1+x^2)dx=\sqrt{n}\int_{-n^{-{1}/{6}}}^{n^{-{1}/{6}}}\exp(-n\log(1+\frac{t^2}{n})dt$
>
> Since $-n\log(1+\frac{t^2}{n})=t^2+O(\frac{1}{n^{1/3}})$
>
> uniformly in $|t|\leqslant n^{\frac{1}{6}}$, we obtain
>
> $I_2=(1+O(\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}))(\sqrt{\pi}-\int_{-\infty}^{-n^{1/6}}e^{-t^2}dt-\int_{n^{1/6}}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt)=\sqrt{\pi}+O(\frac{1}{n^{1/3}})$
>
> as $n\to\infty$. On the other hand it follows that
>
> $0<I_1+I_2<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(1+n^{-2/3})^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$
> and right-hand side convergence to $0$ as $n\to\infty$

**Questions**:

**1)** How does the author establishes this equality $-n\log(1+\frac{t^2}{n})=t^2+O(\frac{1}{n^{1/3}})$?

**2)** How did he deduce the following $I_2=(1+O(\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}))(\sqrt{\pi}-\int_{-\infty}^{-n^{1/6}}e^{-t^2}dt-\int_{n^{1/6}}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt)$? Where does the $\sqrt{\pi}$ come from?

Sorry for the questions but it the first time I solve an integral like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1 comes directly from the Taylor series $$-\log(1+x) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{x^k}{k},$$ which converges for $|x| < 1.$

Comment: (Along with the assumption that $t^2/n<1$)

Comment: I see some typos in the substitution $t=\sqrt{n}x$.

Comment: In $I_2$, you can use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt = \sqrt{\pi},$ so the right parentheses are $\int_{-n^{1/6}}^{n^{1/6}} e^{-t^2}dt$.

Comment: What is this book and who is the author?

Comment: @zhw. Sorry for answering so late. The book is "Problems and Solutions in real analysis" by Masayoshi Hata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another answer suggested, the book's solution is a wild goose chase.

A nice way to see what's going on is to let $x=y/\sqrt n.$ The expression then becomes

$$\tag 1 \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{dy}{(1+y^2/n)^n}.$$

As $n\to \infty,$ $(1+y^2/n)^n\to e^{y^2}$ for any fixed $y.$ So it's reasonable to wonder if the answer is

$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{dy}{e^{y^2}} = \sqrt \pi.$$

This is easy to justify. Just recall that the denominators in $(1)$ increase with $n.$ This shows that a dominating functon for the integrands in $(1)$ is $1/(1+y^2) \in L^1(\mathbb R ).$ The DCT then finishes it off.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant proof!

Answer (score 2):

The book's solution is rather stupid, in my opinion. I propose a different approach. With residues we have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\text{d}x}{(1+x^2)^n} \to \oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{\text{d}z}{(1+z^2)^n}$$

Which has poles at $z = \pm i$ of oder $n$.

Using the multi-poles residues formula

$$2\pi i \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}z^n}\lim_{z\to +i} \left((z-i)^n \frac{1}{(z+i)^n(z-i)^n}\right)$$

and arranging a bit we can easily get the answer:

$$\boxed{\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n)}}$$

Where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ denotes the Euler Gamma Function.

The computation of

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}\Gamma(n-1/2)}{\Gamma(n)}$$

Is rather easy, and gives you $1$, whence

$$\sqrt{\pi}\cdot 1 = \sqrt{\pi}$$

As wanted.

Comment: It depends. Maybe they did not come to complex integration yet.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\pi\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!}$.  Stirling's formula can then be used to get the desired limit.

Comment: I used the Stiring's formula and got $\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!}=\frac{(2n-2)!}{((n-1)!2^{n-1})}$, which is approximated by $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(n-1)}}$, so the original limit is $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg That is another interesting way to solve the problem!

Comment: @Von Neumann  It also is a lot simpler.  Tables of integrals helps!

Comment: @herbsteinberg It's simpler, but I have to say I'm against tables of integrals lol. It's ways more amusing to work by hands :D

Answer (score 1):

For (1),
since
$x-x^2/2
\lt \ln(1+x)
\lt x
$,

$\begin{array}\\
n \ln(1+t^2/n)
&\lt n(t^2/n)\\
&= t^2\\
\text{and}\\
n \ln(1+t^2/n)
&\gt n(t^2/n-t^4/(2n^2))\\
&= t^2-t^4/(2n)\\
&\gt t^2-(n^{1/6})^4/(2n)
\qquad\text{since }|t| \le n^{1/6}\\
&= t^2-n^{-1/3}/2\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica knows 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(n-1/2)}
{\Gamma(n)}. $$ Asymptotics of $\Gamma$ gets the answer.  This is how I'd work the problem.  If you need to prove the right hand side, you could work with the easy integral with integrand $1/(1+a\,x^2)$ and successively differentiate.